# Word for always comparing things to the biggest and best

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've been trying to find a word or brief phrase that describes a person who constantly emphasises, or compares, the size of things, superlatives.

E.g. I watched a TV programme recently, the host was describing a production line, and he was constantly (and irritatingly) pointing out the figures about how "good" the machine is - things such as line speed, units produced per hour etc - emphasising the quantitative facts rather than the qualitative information.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to a suitable word or short phrase that might be appropriate in this case?

Comment: Uhm... _"We're gonna build a wall, it's gonna be [**huuuge**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHxqAxNU3Is)!"_

Comment: How about [Grandiose](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grandiose)?

Comment: A blowhard a trumpest or a limbaugher

Answer (score 2):

There are of course many adjectives for describing such a person. My favorite is :

> bom·bas·tic
>   ˌ>bämˈbastik/
>   adjective
>   high-sounding but with little meaning; inflated.
>   "bombastic rhetoric"
>   synonyms:   pompous, blustering, turgid, verbose, orotund, high-flown, high-sounding, overwrought, pretentious, ostentatious, grandiloquent;

Answer (score 1):

**Overblow** — [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overblow)

> *verb* to give excessive importance or value to
>   *"to overblow one's own writing."*

Answer (score 1):

I'd describe it as pretentious language.

> *Pretentious ADJECTIVE* Attempting to impress by affecting greater importance or merit than is actually possessed:
>
> pretentious art films
>
> the pretentious jargon of wine experts - [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pretentious#pretentious__2)

Comment: Using "pretentious" will imply that the numbers that anchor is speaking of are presumably pretentious (or exaggerated) when we don't know if they are.

Comment: @Mohit what makes you say that pretentious language refers solely to numbers?

Comment: Well, you might be right... I am sorry. Wrong idea in my head.

Comment: @Mohit importance or merit is certainly not restricted to numbers. Just look at the example about pretentious jargon of wine experts. They are not throwing around numbers. They use a lot of fancy adjectives to make themselves and the wines seem more important.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question.

I suggest you to use **puffer** *(as in puffer fish)* derived from [**puff up**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/puff+up). *(also look for [**puffery**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/puffery) in *The Free Dictionary*)

> **puff up:** puff someone or something up; to boost or promote someone or something: *"Judy puffed Nell up so much that Nell could not begin to live up to her reputation. Don't puff up your own accomplishments so much."*

Consider that type of advertisements are also called **[free puff](https://books.google.be/books?id=DV8FCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=free%20puff%20meaning&source=bl&ots=SW2LsFooHs&sig=4-KRmT3gTE_1wAHXpWSB_rH2g8A&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7oMrngtfOAhVLC8AKHZiMCkMQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=free%20puff%20meaning&f=false)** (Jefkins, F., International Dictionary of Marketing and Communication, Retrieved from [International Dictionary of Marketing and Communication](https://books.google.be/books?id=DV8FCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=free%20puff%20meaning&source=bl&ots=SW2LsFooHs&sig=4-KRmT3gTE_1wAHXpWSB_rH2g8A&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7oMrngtfOAhVLC8AKHZiMCkMQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=free%20puff%20meaning&f=false)).

I hope this answers your question well.

Comment: Please also mention the source by name, not just link to it. :)

Comment: @NVZ Thank you for the correction, edited as you have suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, a ***quantitative*** *person*.

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quantitative):

> ***quantitative***
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Relating to, measuring, or measured by the **quantity of something rather than its quality**: quantitative analysis
>
> Often contrasted with qualitative.
>
> More example sentences:
>
> Yet this is in many ways a quantitative rather than a qualitative
> distinction.
>
> Evaluation may involve subjective and objective measures
> and qualitative and quantitative approaches.
>
> That may be appropriate,
> but using these qualitative data for quantitative statistics is
> fraught with difficulty.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantitative):

> ***quantitative***
> *adjective*
> Simple Definition of quantitative : of or relating to how much there
> is of something : of or relating to the quantity or amount of
> something

From [businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/quantitative.html):

> ***quantitative***
> Associated with an objective quality of a thing or phenomenon that is measurable and verifiable, such as lightness or
> heaviness, softness or hardness, and thickness or thinness

Usage example [(a blog post) at chicagonow.com](http://www.chicagonow.com/mba-mom/2016/03/a-week-with-two-sick-children-by-the-numbers/):

> Since I am a **quantitative person** by nature, here is a look back at
> my week that was in numbers so you can see how I got the little ones
> better.